# Require a regex expression to identify only alphanumeric

Tags: python, regex

I have 12 different strings as following:

```
Abc123
Abc
123
123abhcp3648_123
1256145avhasfjscb
jasbfhjbscsdf3t67235
_sfbjbf_jsbfsdbf_jsjsbfs_hjhuhu
5nm_ch0_rxtx2_synthon_mask
5nm_ch0_rxtx2_synthon_mask_s
5responsemessage
response546
wouldli234_qws_
```

I would like to figure out a regex expression to identify only the following strings:

```
123abhcp3648_123
_sfbjbf_jsbfsdbf_jsjsbfs_hjhuhu
5nm_ch0_rxtx2_synthon_mask
5nm_ch0_rxtx2_synthon_mask_s
wouldli234_qws_
```

Here I would like to extract alphanumeric with underscores from two formats along with underscores(numerics followed by alphabets and alphabets followed by numerics)

Comment: Based on your examples, you really just need to check for an underscore. `'_' in s`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Stack Overflow is not the place to get others to do all your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like all you really need to check for is the presence of at least one underscore:

`\w*_\w*`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HbtMe8/1

Comment: I suppose `.*_.*` would work as well and it looks cuter :)

Comment: @MadWombat Normally I would have done that, but OP specifically mentioned alphanumeric characters, so I just wanted to be safe.